# How to create dynamical table with column using T-SQL in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I will create a table and some columns dynamically in SQL Server. I have the following stored procedure and generate columns inside a loop, but I have no idea about how to putting code inside loop to generatoe columns with the column name like this (Name_1).....(Name_N) and their data type are (Nvarchar(10))

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_buildtbldynamically
    @tbl_Name nvarchar(10),
    @num_col int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Counter int
    SET @Counter = 1

    DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQLString = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @tbl_Name + '(AB_ID PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL' +

    WHILE @Counter <= @num_col
    BEGIN
        // generator columns here dynamically with name (Name_1........Name_N)

       SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1  
    END
END
```

Comment: It is possible using Dynamic query but why on earth you are doing this

Comment: Dear Prdp :D I have a table contains a lot columns (Name_1 ... Name_N)

Comment: good_well that still does not explains why you would need this

Comment: If you already have a table, why are you creating it? :)

Comment: GuidoG I want to create a table that is contains a lot column with (Name_1,Name_2,Name_3......Name_N) I can't creating one by one.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
create PROCEDURE sp_buildtbldynamically
@tbl_Name nvarchar(10),
@num_col int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Counter int
    SET @Counter =1
    DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)
    -- does the table exists? If not, create
    if not exists(select 1 from sys.tables t where t.[name]=@tbl_Name)
        begin
            SET @SQLString = 'CREATE TABLE [' + @tbl_Name + '](AB_ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL)'
            exec sp_executesql @SQLString
        end

    while @Counter <= @num_col
        Begin
            set @SQLString='alter table ['+@tbl_Name+'] add [Name_'+cast(@Counter as varchar(2))+'] int'
            exec sp_executesql @SQLString
            print @SQLString
            SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1  
        END
END
go
exec dbo.sp_buildtbldynamically 'bob',3
go
```

LOTS of things to consider however.

1. Does the table exist? (if added a check as an example)
2. What are the datatypes for the created columns?
3. what if the @num_col is set to 1,000,000 (or some huge figure).
4. What is the columns already exists?

These answers you now must consider but you have an answer to your question

Comment: Dear J F thank you for your answer my question maximum number of columns in table  about 30 to 40 and I have about 80 tables with different name have the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code helps you to create dynamic columns prefixed with 'Name_'

```
DECLARE @DynamiccOlumns nvarchar(max)
;With cte
AS
(
SELECT  'Name_'+CAST(Sno AS VARCHAR(10))AS Names FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT number)) AS Sno FROM master..spt_values
)DT
WHERE DT.Sno<=10
)
SELECT DISTINCT @DynamiccOlumns=  STUFF((SELECT ', '+  Names +' nvarchar(10)' FROM cte FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
FROM cte
SELECT @DynamiccOlumns  AS Names
```

Comment: Dear Srini131, thank you for your answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a loop, you could use a recursive query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_buildtbldynamically @tbl_Name nvarchar(10), @num_col int
AS
BEGIN
    declare @query nvarchar(max) = N'CREATE TABLE ['+@tbl_name+N']('
    ;with sql_rte as
    (
        select cast('[Name_1] [nvarchar](10)' as nvarchar(max)) col,1 rn
        union all
        select cast(',[Name_'+cast(rn+1 as varchar)+'] [nvarchar](10)' as nvarchar(max)) ,rn+1
        from sql_rte
        where rn<@num_col
    )
    select @query += col
    from sql_rte

    set @query += N')'
    exec sp_executesql @query
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot create a table with all the columns at the time of creation of table then you can first create the table and then update the table to add all the columns that you require based on the `num_col` values passed to the stored procedure.

You can modify the stored procedure as below to get that started and running:

```
Create PROCEDURE sp_buildtbldynamically
  @tbl_Name nvarchar(10),
  @num_col int
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Counter int
  SET @Counter =1
  DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)
  SET @SQLString = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @tbl_Name + '(AB_ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL)'
  Exec(@SQLString)
  while @Counter <= @num_col
    Begin
      Declare @SQL varchar(100)
      Declare @Name varchar(100)
      Set @Name = 'Name_' + Cast(@Counter as varchar(5));
      SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @tbl_Name + ' ADD ' + @Name + ' INT'
      EXEC (@SQL)
      SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1  
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that instead of loop use a tally/number table approach.

Query will be like below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_buildtbldynamically
    @tbl_Name nvarchar(10),
    @num_col int
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQLString = 
     'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[' + @tbl_Name + ']([AB_ID] [INT] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL'
    -- generator columns here dynamicall with name (Name_1........Name_N)
    SELECT 
        TOP (SELECT @num_col)
        @SQLString=COALESCE(@SQLString, '') + 
        ', [Name_'+ CAST( ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))  AS VARCHAR(10)) +
        ']  [nvarchar](10) NULL'
    FROM SYS.OBJECTS S1 CROSS JOIN SYS.OBJECTS S2
    SET @SQLString=@SQLString+ ' ) ON [PRIMARY];'
    exec (@SQLString)

END
```